# Set Campaign member status to Responded as default, not Sent (Automatically)

Tags: apex, campaign, campaign-member

I'd like to set the Campaign Member status value to Responded as default. I know we could that at the campaign record in Advance menu setup. But I'd like it to happen automatically, not manually changed.

[image]

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2):

This is [under consideration for Summer '17](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br5dAAC). Currently, you can specify the default picklist values, but you cannot specify a default status value. Make sure you add your vote while you're there. They also mentioned that there's a [free app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005utCcEAI) you can use that lets you do stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a trigger whenever a campaign is added such that it creates two members status, sent and responded.

trigger createMembeStatus on Campaign (after Insert){

```
List<CampaignMemberStatus> cms = new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();
for (Campaign c: trigger.new){
        CampaignMemberStatus cms1 = new CampaignMemberStatus(CampaignId=c.Id, HasResponded=true, Label='Responded', SortOrder=3, IsDefault=true);            
        CampaignMemberStatus cms2 = new CampaignMemberStatus(CampaignId=c.Id, HasResponded=False, Label='Sent', SortOrder=4, IsDefault=false);  
       cms.add(cms1);
       cms.add(cms2);
    }
    insert cms;
```

}

Comment: `if(cms.size() > 0)` is no longer required.

Comment: thank you for reminding that. I used similar code where i create status after checking a condition, hence that extra if statement which i forgot to remove.